# Reading a HttpPostedFile before saving it saves a blank file in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, filestream

Before saving an uploaded csv file I want to check it will parse. When I was just saving the file everything was fine, now that I'm reading it first the file saved is blank.

Here is my action method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Import(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    // Check parse went ok
    using (var fileStream = file.InputStream)
    {
        if (!MemberFileParsingService.CheckFileWillParse(fileStream))
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "There was a problem with the file";
            return View();
        }
    }

    // Save file so we can work on it in next action
    file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(fileName));

    return RedirectToAction("ImportMatch", new { club = ActiveClub.Url });
}
```

And here's my method that checks to see if the file parses ok. It uses CsvReader to read through the whole file to check there are no errors. CsvReader throws exceptions when it comes to bad bits of the file.

```
public static bool CheckFileWillParse(Stream fileStream)
{
    try
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
        {
            using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader, false))
            {
                while (csv.ReadNextRecord()) { }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I think it's probably because it's trying to write the file using the same stream that is now at the end of the file. I don't know how to reset the stream though. I was hoping all my using statements would fix that problem.

So how can I reset the stream, or is that just a red herring?

**Update:** Found the length of the stream gets reset to zero after going through CheckFileWillParse so looks like resetting the stream is just a red herring and the stream is actually being blanked somehow.

Comment: Same thing happens if construct a StreamReader from the HttpInputStream object, read a line to check the header is correct, and then reuse the stream (into a 3rd party library). Can't seem to seek to the beginning of the file or ever get that line back. Most annoying!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered creating a copy of the stream to analyse, using `Stream.CopyTo()`?

Comment: This may be easier. Going to try some tweaks to make @Brians solution work, then will try this.

Comment: Resetting the original stream (if you can) would be a much cleaner solution. I'll be interested to see how you get on.

Comment: The stream was getting blanked in CheckFileWillParse when I closed the streamreader so decided your idea to copy the stream was the best one so the stream passed in to the function remained unchanged.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, it was an interesting problem.

Answer (score 5):

You have to rewind the stream (if possible).  Once you are doing reading it, the current position is at the end of the stream, that is why the file is empty when you save it.

You can use either the Seek function or the Position property to do this (set it to 0).  Not all stream types support this though.

If a stream type doesn't support it, you may need to write the file out to disk first, then run your test against it.

Comment: It can seek but adding fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin) doesn't seem to have helped. It may be because the stream's length is 0 after CheckFileWillParse for some reason.

Comment: Turns out the position thing was a red herring. Save as resets the position itself. Turns out that closing the closing the stream reader blanked the stream.

Comment: You're right, I should have noticed that you were closing the StreamReader; When you did that, it closed the underlying Stream.  I've run into that issue before. Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 3):

Since the StreamReader Dispose Method will dispose your underlying Stream as well.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
myStream.CopyTo(ms);
myStream.Position = ms.Position = 0; // !Don't forget this!
//And then read your 'ms' here
```

Answer (score 3):

Because of the `using` statement, the `Dispose()` method on your `StreamReader` object will be called.  This will actually close the underlying `Stream` object.  Hence why the stream is of zero length.

**Option 1:**

One option is to not dispose of the `StreamReader` instance by removing the `using` statement.  You will need to manually dispose of the stream later (but maybe `CsvReader` will do this for you) by calling its `Dispose()` method.

The garbage collector will clean up the `StreamReader` object and will not close the underlying stream.

**Option 2:**

You can use the [following constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/gg712853%28v=VS.110,d=hv.2%29.aspx) when instantiating `StreamReader`:

```
public StreamWriter(
    Stream stream,
    Encoding encoding,
    int bufferSize,
    bool leaveOpen
)
```

Setting the `leaveOpen` parameter to `true` will ensure that the stream will not be closed.

Comment: That constructor is for StreamWriter.